# R ttest on multiple levels of a factor

Tags: r

I'm trying to perform multiple t-test on my dataset in r and got totally confused from the capabilities of apply functions, aggregate and for loops.
My data is as following: I have observations which are different products. for each product I have multiple numeric variables, which I'd like to compare. In addition, I have 13 different categories of products. AND, I have another factor variable which differentiate between new, used, and old products. So a sample of my data may look as the following:

```
ProdID  Category    Cond    No. of instances    Sales   Time since launch
aaaaa   Sports       New          100           40000         30
bbbb    Crafts       New           0              0           20
ccccc   Music       Used           20            1000         10
```

My goal is to perform the following, I want to output separately, for each Category (Sports, Crafts, Music etc.) the results of a t-test. This t-test should compare means of each numeric var, with the comparison of "New" mean to "Used" mean (I'm not interested in "old" values at all). So at the end I want to see the comparison of "Time since launch"m "Sales" and "Num Instances" between new and old in Sports, then the same in crafts, the same in music etc....

I've tried it in so many ways, but in each of them (aggreagte, tapply, for loop) I had a different problem... It seems that I'm missing here something (I'm kind of new in R. I used to do it in spss and used split file...)

Comment: for some reason my table isn't posted as i want to be posted, the idea is that i have the columns: prodID, Category, Cond,... and i added some instances: aaa, bbbb, ccc as examples of observations...

Comment: Your proposed statistical approach is deeply flawed. I would urge you to contact a statistician. You really can't compare count data with a t-test. Then there is the multiple testing problem.

Comment: Thanks, but this is just an example for simplifying my requirements. My real data is composed of multiple continuous variables, but it is much more complex to explain... Please regard them as continuous, in reality they really are such.